# Try to prove or disprove first?

Tags: logic

Question constraints:

- hypothesis is universal or existential
- hypothesis is falsifiable and can be supported to be true
- evidence has to be empirical: specific examples that either support the hypothesis or not (the question is not for deductive proofs)
- working on proving something will make it more likely for you to find supporting evidence of hypothesis being true while working on disproving will make it more likely to find supporting evidence that the hypothesis is false
- there is no evidence at the start to believe hypothesis is true or false

Under the constraints above does it make sense to work first on *proving* or *disproving*?

Depending on what the goal is (proving, disproving, or both) someone might take different set of actions.

For example if the proposition is "All swans are white" which we know to be false then depending on the goal the researcher might take different actions:

- If the goal he chose is to prove all swans are white then his actions will probably be made so that he can see more white swans and count them as evidence - basically searching geographically close to areas he already knew there are white swans.
- If the goal he chose is to disprove that all swans are white he would probably be searching farther away from well known locations of white swans because that would make it more likely to find genetically diverse swans that way.

This shows that depending on the prove/disprove goal one might take different set of actions.

There are also cases in which proving and disproving can be achieved by taking the same steps. For example when theory of relativity was proven using gravitational lensing seen during a solar eclipse all the steps to prove or disprove were the same with the last step proving or disproving the hypothesis.

For an universal claim it is enough to have one counterexample to disproves it. And for existential claims there is enough to have 1 example to prove it.

**Reasons why it seems there has to be an optimal order:**

For the reasons below I will operate under the set up that all tests are correct. For purpose of showing my point introducing test errors would just fuzzy the probabilities a bit so it is not important.

Having the universal hypothesis: all swans are white.

If you are able to analyze all the swans and they are all white then you can say that you are 100% certain the hypothesis is true. Let's say you decide to try to prove first, you pick a swan and look at it: it is white. Does that mean you just shown with 100% chance that all swans are white? Can someone claim that 1 white swan proves with 100% chance that all swans are white - you can only say that by looking at all swans. Otherwise it is just extrapolation form 1 example. One swan provides some percentage chance that all swans are white, 2 swans increase that percentage, but any number of white swans except analyzing all of them can not provide 100% certainty that all swans are white. This shows that by choosing to prove first the chance of hypothesis being true is less than 100%.

Now let's say you try to disprove first. You find a black swan. The hypothesis has been disproven. You have 100% shown that not all swans are white. 100% shown, not under 100% like when you find any non total number of white swans.

Because 1 example for disproving is always 100% and 1 example for proving is under 100% you always want to start by disproving.

Similar example is for existential proof: there exists a black swan. It is sufficient to find 1 black swan to 100% show that black swans exists and no number of white swans can disprove that.

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for here.  As a general matter, it is often easier to proceed as if one knew the answer already.  That is, if you believe the claim to be true, try to prove it but if you believe it to be false, try to disprove it.  Of course, in either case you must keep an open mind and stay prepared to "switch sides" as it were.  Is that the sort of thing you are asking?

Comment: Phrased differently, I do not believe there is a useful, universal way to attack an open question.  For questions about numbers, say, I'll typically start with a search because it's (often) easy and sometimes it settles the point (by producing a counterexample, say).  Even if it doesn't settle the point it often gives you some interesting cases and may suggest a useful pattern. But, again, these are just things one tries...not a rigorous methodology.

Comment: maybe useful : [Scientific Discovery](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-discovery/#DisBetConDisConJus) as well as [Heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic).

Comment: @lulu I think the setup I am looking for is  that there is no evidence at the start to believe it is true or false (I added that constraint to the question). So is there any optimal way in which to work on it: prove, disprove or both? If there is no optimal way that means any goal of proving, disproving or both might yield a result with equal probabilities.

Comment: Isn't this more suited to Philosophy SE?

Comment: You can always choose a side even if your confidence is low. It's a tactic, not a rigorous philosophy.  My number theory example was agnostic...you could say it's a search for a counterexample, but it would be more accurate to say that it's a convenient way to dig in to the problem.  Sometimes it works immediately, sometimes it gives you some interesting leads to pursue, sometimes it is useless. But, as a general matter, I do not believe that there is a universally useful methodology.

Comment: @lulu Doesn't the fact that you only need 1 counterexample to disprove an universal statement make it more logical to start with the goal of disproving instead of proving?

Comment: Sometimes, sure.  Not always.  I really don't think there's some optimal strategy that always works.

Comment: @lulu But if sometimes it makes sense to try disproving first yet there are no examples in which it makes sense to prove first then overall it always makes sense to start by disproving since in worst case it won't yield any difference and in best case it would be more optimal.

Answer (score 5):

> *Problems worthy of attack
>
>   prove their worth by fighting back.*
>   ([Piet Hein](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/75064-problems-worthy-of-attack-prove-their-worth-by-fighting-back))

If you start by trying to prove it, but you get stuck, then you can use the information (how you got stuck) to try for a counterexample.  But then if you get stuck on building a counterexample, you can use the new information from doing that to try for a proof.  In good problems, you may go back and forth several times.  Until you either get one that works, or you give up.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no optimal goal (proving, disproving or both) to start with?

Comment: Your answer is not actually answering the question. I recommend editing it to answer the question or just deleting it otherwise.

Comment: To explain why this is not an answer: there is no mention of whether there exists an optimal goal (proving, disproving or both) or not.

Comment: See "Reasons why it seems there has to be an optimal order" section in my question. It might help you with answering the question.